# How to get the text of nested tag with Beautifulsoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

After running this code

`section = soup.find_all('section', class_='b-branches')`

I get

`<div class="b-branches__item"><i class="icon fa"><b>Firm</b> </i>RJT Roadlines</div>`

Now i want to just extract **RJIT Roadlines** only not...Firm

So i tried

`for i in section: firm = i.find('div', class_='b-branches__item') print(firm)`

It will return both **Firm** and **RJIT Roadlines**

So, how to extract only div tag's text??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
When asking for debugging help, we ask that you condense your code by making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
This is helpful for people to understand your problem without having to go through the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tag.contents[1]` to get your expected output.

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="b-branches__item"><i class="icon fa"><b>Firm</b> </i>RJT Roadlines</div>
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

tag = soup.find('div', class_='b-branches__item')
print(tag.contents[1])
```

**Output:**

```
RJT Roadlines
```

Comment: Suppose after using print(tag.contents[1]) i got output i.e 987,9887. Now how to store them in two different variable x1, x2.

Comment: Not clearly what you mean, you should ask it as new question with full example. If I understand right, just assign it `x1 = soup.find('div', class_='b-branches__item').contents[1]`